# unable to create list view in android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am passing string array to a bundle from one activity to other I wish to display this string array in list view on 2nd activity.But the list view is not created.Following is the code for same:

//welcome.java

```
package com.example.eleave;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Welcome extends Activity {
       int l;
    Button b1,b2;
    EditText e1,e2;
     String result2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
        b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        e1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        e2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(e1.getText().length()==0 ||e2.getText().length()==0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Enter all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    String username=e1.getText().toString();
                String password=e2.getText().toString();
                AsyncTask<String, Void, String> s=new SignUp(Welcome.this,username,password).execute(username,password);
                try{
        String result=s.get();
         String password1=password+"0";
           String password2=password+"1";
       if(result.equals(password1))
       {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"student", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i=new Intent(Welcome.this,LeaveApp.class);
             Bundle b=new Bundle();
                b.putString("username", username);
                i.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(i);
       }
       else if(result.equals(password2))
       {
String usernam[]=new String[20];
            String phone_no1[]=new String[20];
            String reason[]=new String[20];
            String sem[]=new String[20];
            String from_date[]=new String[20];
            String to_date[]=new String[20];
          // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "teacher", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           AsyncTask<String,Void,String>id1=new CountRows(Welcome.this).execute();
           try{
               result2= id1.get();
                l=Integer.parseInt(result2);
           }catch(Exception e)
           {

           }
           AsyncTask<String,Void,String>id=new Upload(Welcome.this).execute();
           try{
              String result1= id.get();
            int j=0;
            for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
            {
        String div[]=result1.split("-");
         phone_no1[i]=div[j++];
         reason[i]=div[j++];
         sem[i]=div[j++];
         from_date[i]=div[j++];
         to_date[i]=div[j++];
        // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), phone_no1[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         AsyncTask<String,Void,String>id3=new GetUser(Welcome.this).execute(phone_no1[i]);
           try{
              String result3= id3.get();
              usernam[i]=result3;
              }catch(Exception e)
              {

              }



            }
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), phone_no1[0]+reason[0]+sem[0]+from_date[0]+to_date[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),result1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }catch(Exception e)
           {

           }
           Intent i=new Intent(Welcome.this,View_Stud.class);

               Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
               bundle.putStringArray("phoneno",phone_no1);
               bundle.putStringArray("reason",reason);
               bundle.putStringArray("sem",sem);
               bundle.putStringArray("from_date",from_date);
               bundle.putStringArray("to_date",to_date);
                bundle.putStringArray("username", usernam);
                bundle.putInt("length", l);
                i.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(i);
           }

        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
                }catch(Exception e)
                {

                }}

            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent i=new Intent(Welcome.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

//view_stud.java

package com.example.eleave;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class View_Stud extends Activity{



    String[] phno,reason,sem,fdate,tdate;
    String[] uname;
    int len;
    ListView lv1;
    String str[]=new String[30];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_stud);
         Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
           String phno[]= bundle.getStringArray("phoneno");
           String reason[]= bundle.getStringArray("reason");
           String sem[]=bundle.getStringArray("sem");
         String  fdate[]=bundle.getStringArray("from_date");
        String  tdate[]= bundle.getStringArray("to_date");
      String uname[]=bundle.getStringArray("username");
       int len=bundle.getInt("length");
         for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
         {
             str[i]=uname[i]+sem[i];
         }


        lv1=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ad=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,str);

        lv1.setAdapter(ad);
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Approve_Stud.class);


                i.putExtra("data2", str[arg2]);
                startActivity(i);

            }

        });

    }
}
```

//logcat error

```
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1409)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8314)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8314)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8314)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8314)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8314)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:843)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1866)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
04-22 16:34:37.420: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: i want to create a listview of str[] which takes its values obtained from the previous activity through bundle.But it is not working.It is not going from the previous activity to current listview activity

Comment: Can you post your logcat if it shows any error?

Comment: Initialize the str object to the length of the data you want to it. Currently i am unable to see str = new String[length];

Comment: what is at `view_stud.xml` for which you have set `setContentView(R.layout.view_stud)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check which overloaded constructor of ArrayAdapter you are using, one of them as items accepts Array another ArrayList. Also I think with your Array object **str** there is syntax error, you haven't created array object properly. You can use array list that is object that behaves similary to array but you don't have to worry much about indexes because ArrayList can change its capacity dynamically

Comment: Thank you everyone.I solved the problem by changing string array to arraylist

Answer (score 0):

initialize `str[]`  to here

```
 int len=bundle.getInt("length");

 String str[]=new String[len];

     for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
     {
         str[i]=uname[i]+sem[i];
     }
```